# Stop WP from creating "Sample Page" and "Hello World!" post

Tags: posts, pages

Is it possible to stop WP from creating the "Sample Page" and "Hello World!" post when creating a new blog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***If you're using Multisite***

The accepted answer is destructive in that it cancels all other set-up items in the overridden function. A less destructive way to do it *for multisite installs* is to delete the default content during new blog creation by hooking in to `wpmu_new_blog`

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'delete_wordpress_defaults', 100, 1 );

function delete_wordpress_defaults(){

    // 'Hello World!' post
    wp_delete_post( 1, true );

    // 'Sample page' page
    wp_delete_post( 2, true );
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Create a file `install.php` in your `wp-content` directory. In that file you declare the `wp_install_defaults()` function. If you just leave that function empty no default categories, links, posts or pages will be created.

The default (pluggable) `wp_install_defaults()` function can be found in `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php`.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550086/how-to-delete-the-default-hello-world-post-before-wordpress-install

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea to solve the problem with WP Multisite? After adding the install.php in the wp-content directory I get a 500 Error when creating new site.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment—the 500 Error was caused by something else! Also works for Multisite!

Comment: This will also cancel the creation of the 'Uncategorized' category, and a host of other settings. check the function at the following link to see what exactly you'll be overriding: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L130

Comment: Please see my answer below for a less destructive way of doing this _for multisite installs_ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/272252/13118